# How to show a node view after clearing cache?

Tags: views, 8, nodes, path-aliases

I'm running into an odd situation with views and pathauto not showing a node. Here is what is happening:

- I have created a content type called "Āsana". In it, there are several fields and paragraphs.
- I have created a node called "Śirṣāsana" that has a safe name called "sirsasana".
- I have set up a Pathauto alias with the pattern, `asana/[node:field_safe_name]`. To navigate to the Śirṣāsana page, I can go to `http://mysite.loc/asana/sirsasana`
- I have also created a view that shows a full page of a single "Āsana" node. The page path is set to `/node/%`, and the contextual filter is set to `Content: ID`. Here is a screenshot of it...

[image: Āsana view screenshot]

- When I navigate to the page `http://mysite.loc/asana/sirsasana`, I see all of the content that the view is supposed to display.
- If I rebuild the caches (`drush cr`) and navigate back to the page (`http://mysite.loc/asana/sirsasana`), all of the content is gone.
- In order to see the content, I have to go to `admin/structure/views`, edit the "Āsana" view, and save it. Note that there are no changes to the view. There is no asterisk (*) by any of the view tabs. I just have to save the view, navigate back to the page, and then I can see the content. All of the content disappears when I rebuild the caches again.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my views setup? Is it Pathauto?

Comment: At the very top, I see you have 2 other views, `12 basic ...` and `All asana ...`. Are these views also page views? If yes, what are their paths?

Comment: No, these are entity reference list views that populate select fields. They don't have paths.

Comment: Makes no sense that when you go to `http://mysite.loc/asana/sirsasana` you see all the stuff the `Full Page` view displays. Are you using Panels? Maybe someone added this view to the panel?

Comment: Unless you are seeing either `12 basic` or `All sana` views. Since these are blocks. Check the visibility settings (in configure block) of these view blocks.

Comment: The full page is there until I clear the cache. Then everything is gone and it doesn't come back until I go to the view and save it again. After that, everything is back to normal. I'm not seeing the other two views. They are just lists with titles only. When I see the full page, I'm seeing all the fields.

Comment: I'm not using panels

Comment: /node/% is already in use by the node entity. In general you can overwrite routes, see the view for taxonomy. But two things are different. First the taxonomy route is declared in a yaml file, the node route is declared in an entity route provider. Don't know if this causes the strange behavior on cache clear. Second for a content type specific view this wouldn't work, because if you override the route successfully you have to deliver the content for all content types. By only filtering one the rest will have a blank page.

Comment: So you are using a view to control the output of a single node? That's pretty inefficient and there are various tools for this available, core view display settings + templates, display suite, page manager/panels.. The view also means you apply this to *all* node types, which means you can't do something different for a different node type. All other mentioned concepts have options to configure the display per node type

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I'll have to take a different approach and learn more about the routing system.